# How long can this ALTER TABLE statement take?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, alter-table, ddl

```
Alter TABLE [XXX] Alter column [YYY] [varchar](max) NULL
```

Suppose

- there are 45 GB data space and 2GB index space;
- about 3 million rows in this table;
- column YYY is `varchar(8000)` now and can be updated (is writable).
- the table has about 30 other columns.
- There are about 3000G data from other database & tables on this machine.

Some other information:

- 99.99% of rows have `NULL` in this `varchar(8000)`;
- the web application may hit this table 5 times per minute;
- the hardware is enterprise level (8 core CPU and 256GB RAM).
- there are other tables and database on this machine, about 3000GB data.

Relevant `@@VERSION` details:

> Microsoft **SQL Server 2014** - 12.0.4422.0 (X64) 
> **Enterprise** Edition (64-bit)

Comment: If 99.99% of rows have a null VARCHAR(8000) column it rather suggests that it is not really part of the entity that the table is supposed to model.  Perhaps you would be better having a 1 to 0..1 relationship with the object in a different table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody can tell you with any degree of certainty or accuracy how long this operation will take on your system. However I suggest the change will likely have less impact than you think. I set up a quick test to compare changing a table from `int` -> `bigint` and from `varchar(8000)` -> `varchar(max)`. First, two simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t0(a int primary key, b int);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(a int primary key, b varchar(8000));
GO
```

Now, insert at least one non-NULL value, and then over 5 million rows (on my system; YMMV):

```
INSERT dbo.t0 VALUES(0,1);
INSERT dbo.t0 SELECT rn, NULL FROM 
( SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
) AS x;
GO -- 5,299,204 rows for me

INSERT dbo.t1 VALUES(0,'what');
INSERT dbo.t1 SELECT rn, NULL FROM 
( SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
) AS x;
GO -- 5,299,204 rows for me
```

Then I tested the `ALTER` change, with stats I/O enabled:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.t0 ALTER COLUMN b bigint NULL; 
GO -- 9 seconds, 122,506 reads
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
```

This finished in 9 seconds and required 122,506 reads.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.t1 ALTER COLUMN b varchar(max) NULL; 
GO -- 5 seconds, 8,562 logical reads
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
```

This finished in 5 seconds and only required 8,562 reads.

So while neither operation happened online, and while your actual results may differ based on hardware and your table structure, this was on a lowly Windows VM on a MacBook, so I would expect your time to be better than this.

I also tested with a lot more data populated in the nullable column. Dropped the tables, re-created and re-populated with the above scripts, then ran this to put *something* in 100,000 rows:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT TOP (100000) a,b FROM dbo.t1 ORDER BY NEWID())
UPDATE x SET b = a;
GO
;WITH x AS (SELECT TOP (100000) a,b FROM dbo.t1 ORDER BY NEWID())
UPDATE x SET b = REPLICATE(RTRIM(a), 1000);
GO
```

This took *way* longer than the subsequent `ALTER`s (over 3 minutes). The first `ALTER` still took 9 seconds, but the second one took 17, simply because the number of reads shot up (to 189,854). This is similar to what would happen if you had, say, 30 other columns in this table. I still think 17 seconds is pretty good for what is actually happening here, and again, this is far from an enterprise-level environment.

As Paul points out, starting with SQL Server 2016, you can get this to happen online, but there are restrictions and limitations. For more information [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.t1 ALTER COLUMN b varchar(max) NULL WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

This option is not available in SQL Server 2014, though.

One way you could get this to happen more online is to simply move that column to a separate, related table. There are some intricacies here with how you cut over, and it might impact a bunch of code, but you can solve most issues with a view (at least temporarily).

Comment: Hi, I just performed this alter operation in product environment. It did have less impact than I thought. The whole procedure took about one minute. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

A VARCHAR(8000) column won't be indexed as you can only index up to 900 bytes prior to SQL Server 2016 so you don't need to worry about indexes.

You need to consider who and what will be accessing the table when you make that change.  As far as SQL Server is concerned such a change is considered a change of data type so will take longer than a change in VARCHAR size which is considered a metadata change.

What is happening under the hood is that the data in your VARCHAR(8000) column will be shifted out of row and your record will now have a pointer to the data represented by VARCHAR(MAX).

Time to execute will depend on many things such as

- Hardware - Storage performance, RAM
- Utilisation - What other processes are taking place on your box.
- Size of TempDB
- How many of your 3 million records have something in your VARCHAR(8000) field
- How many bytes are actually in your VARCHAR(8000) field.  If most of your records have large strings then this will take a lot of time.

Personally I would rehearse it within a test environment and expect to do it during a quiet time out of business hours.

Comment: Thank you so much. I update the question with some other information . Can you give me some exstimate or suggestions? In fact, I need this to be done in minutes.

Comment: Are you sure the `alter column` cannot be done online?

Comment: @Dave Also, the existing column can be an *included* column in an index.

Answer (score -6):

About the time you need to type it, if the table isn't locked.

It's DDL, not DML, if you doubt my words.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an estimate about it?

Comment: Are you sure the `alter column` can be done online? Not all DDL can be performed online. Some require the whole table to be processed.

Comment: What is there to be processed?   The only thing changing is the definition of one column.

Comment: The data in that column will often need to be moved.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille my question was more general than the specific issue. Because your answer implies that all DDL operations are fast (or online). Which they aren't.

Comment: Well, I was answering only the OP.  My answer implied nothing in general.  This DDL, enlarging an existing varchar column, should take no time.

Comment: Other readers will interpret this answer as you wrote it, in the general case, not specific to this OP's details. Also, I have shown in my answer that it *will* take longer than how long it takes to type it, in this specific case.

Comment: @AaronBertrand To be picky, typing-by-reading-from-this-question the `alter` command took me about 13 seconds, so only your longest execution time (17 seconds) exceeds that (and then only just) :-) I agree with your sentiment, though.

Comment: You are effectively saying, "It will be fast *because* it's DDL, not DML" – as though its being DDL always means it will be fast(er than DML).